# Visa to work in Germany for a short time (2 weeks)

Tags: visa, schengen

My company has its office in Germany and I will be travelling from India for 2 weeks related to work (not merely business meetings). What type of visa I should apply for working there?

Answer (score 1):

Basicly you must apply for a shortime work visa.

It will depend on what type of work you will be doing

- and if it will entail needing permission from the employment office

which your employer should determine before you make the application at the German Embassy or Consulate.

A summary letter, in German, preferably quoting the responce from the employment office, from your German employer will assist in making such an application less painful.

This is a case by case situation which is difficult for the Cousulate to determine by itself.